# Manually set password in FOSUserBundle

Tags: security, symfony, sha512

I need to set user password in datafixtures. But it encodes in `sha512. How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set manually a password in a user, you must used the service **security.encoder_fatcory**.

```
$user->setPassword($this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user)->encodePassword("your password in plain texte here", $user->getSalt()));
```

Comment: and another question, how set field in date format? maybe its stupid question but iam newbie and dont now that)

Comment: `new \DateTime('your date here')`. If you use the `FOSUserBundle` you can set the plain password simply by calling `$user->setPlainPassword('new password')`